# Find all objects with values for keys except duplicates

Tags: sql, mongodb

If I have a DB with this structure

```
{
_id: int
P1: string
P2: [{
    _id: int
    C1: [int]
    C2: int
    C3: string
    C4: string
    C5: [{
        D1: string
        D2: {E1: string}
    }]
    C6: string
    C7: false
}]
}
```

For all P2 objects, we check for duplicate D1 values ​​in C5 and only get non-duplicate P2 objects.

```
{_id:1, P1: "A", P2[{_id: 1, C1:[1], C2:1, C3:"X", C4:"B", C5[{D1:"123", D2:{E1: "331"}}], C6:"Ex", C7:true}]}
{_id:1, P1: "A", P2[{_id: 2, C1:[1], C2:1, C3:"Y", C4:"U", C5[{D1:"456", D2:{E1: "332"}}], C6:"Ea", C7:false}]}
{_id:2, P1: "Z", P2[{_id: 3, C1:[1], C2:2, C3:"I", C4:"O", C5[{D1:"789", D2:{E1: "333"}}], C6:"Eq", C7:false}]}
{_id:2, P1: "Z", P2[{_id: 4, C1:[1], C2:2, C3:"P", C4:"L", C5[{D1:"123", D2:{E1: "334"}}], C6:"Ee", C7:true}]}
```

Therefore, when the following DB structure is constructed, I want this result.

```
{_id:1, P1: "A", P2[{_id: 1, C1:[1], C2:1, C3:"X", C4:"B", C5[{D1:"123", D2:{E1: "331"}}], C6:"Ex", C7:true}]}
{_id:1, P1: "A", P2[{_id: 2, C1:[1], C2:1, C3:"Y", C4:"U", C5[{D1:"456", D2:{E1: "332"}}], C6:"Ea", C7:false}]}
{_id:2, P1: "Z", P2[{_id: 3, C1:[1], C2:2, C3:"I", C4:"O", C5[{D1:"789", D2:{E1: "333"}}], C6:"Eq", C7:false}]}
```

I searched for the `distinct` and`aggregate` functions, but I didn't get the desired results.

Comment: So for each `D1` you want the first `P2` object?

Comment: @tomslabbaert I want to get the rest of the P2 objects except the duplicate D2 values of all the objects in P2.

Comment: So why aren't you returning the last document in you're example? its a different object `{_id: 4, C1:[1], C2:2, C3:"P", C4:"L", C5[{D1:"123", D2:{E1: "334"}}], C6:"Ee", C7:true}]`

Comment: @tomslabbaert I've shown that because the D1 values are duplicates, they are excluded from the results.

Comment: So for each D1 you want the first P2 object that its in as i said in the first comment

Comment: @tomslabbaert Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a simple [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages should be enough:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$P2"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$P2"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$_id"
        }
    }
])
```

If you have a more specific requirement try give a more in depth explanation or add unique cases with their example output.

Comment: We've added a bit more code than the previous one. Please check once.